# My 2009 Pontiac Vibe makes a screeching noise at startup but stops after it starts up

Tags: noise, pontiac, vibe

The screeching noise has been going on for about 4 months. It stops after it has started and does not make the sound again until it has set all day of over night

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your serpentine belt is worn out or that the tensioner pulley is not doing it's job (or both). As you start the engine, there is a high draw on the battery, which power must then be replaced via the alternator. When this happens, there is a large demand put on the alternator. If the serpentine belt or tensioner are not up to the job, then the belt will squeal as it slips on the alternator. As the battery charge is brought back in line to where it's supposed be, the squealing will stop. The noise could also stop once the belt is warm enough and pliable enough to have more *traction* on the drive pulleys.

Which ever reason, getting the belt replaced is a good first step. The tensioner pulley may also have a "range gauge" on it, which will have an arrow pointing to small bracket which should be in the "good" operational range. If the indicator is outside of that range, it's time to replace. Other GM vehicles I've dealt with have something along this line. It would be located in part on the arm of the tensioner and in part on the base of the tensioner where it is mounted to the bracket (if it's there at all).